# WAMP Server for tornado

Tags: python, websocket, tornado

Is there a [wamp](http://wamp.ws/) implementation for [tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/)?

Since we already use tornado, I don't want to set up twisted for this ...

Comment: Curious: apart from "we already use Tornado" (which may of course be a good reason in itself), what does Tornado make attractive or features that Twisted does not?

Comment: @oberstet I tried twisted about eleven years ago. At that time it was too difficult, not straight forward. I am not forced to use tornado. I think I will use your Autobahn module (based on twisted). BTW: The link to WebMQ in our stackoverflow profile is broken. Greating to Erlangen from Chemnitz ..,.

Comment: @oberstet An other point in my case: Package size. We use something which can be compared to JavaWebStart (but in Python). The client downloads the signed code and executes it. But it should be possible to strip the twisted package, if it is necessary at all.

Comment: 11 years ago, ah, ok, early adopter;) guess some progress has been made since then but a learning curve is there. Autobahn comes with lots of examples though. Broken link: thx! WebMQ is no more: we've open-sourced it to Crossbar.io - Greetings to Chemnitz;)

Comment: rgd package size: in fact, Autobahn only needs Twisted Core to run (http://twistedmatrix.com/Releases/Core/13.2/TwistedCore-13.2.0.tar.bz2) - if that is what you meant by "strip the twisted package".

Answer (score 2):

Some of the features of WAMP, on top of Tornado, can be found in this open source project, TornwAMP:
https://github.com/ef-ctx/tornwamp

Comment: Looks good. Except the code uses the GPL licence. I can't use this. GPL is like a virus :-(

Comment: This library seems to have changed to an Apache License now

Answer (score 1):

Not that I am aware of. FWIW, a list of WAMP implementations can be found [here](http://wamp.ws/implementations/).